# Rails 3 Create Script to Manipulate My DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a script to mess around with the db entries in my rails application, but I don't know how to properly set it up to gain access to all my models etc.

I can do this easily with scripts like seeds.rb using 'rake db:seed' to execute or in my application controllers, but I want to create scripts outside of these that I can run in the background or just once.

Do I need to include something, or call the script with a certain rails command?  And as a second related question, is there any way for me to execute rails commands like 'rake db:seed' from within a ruby script?  The only method I know of right now that works is running 'rails console' and executing commands there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'config/environment.rb'
```

When the script is in your rails root...